# Why does the selenium download not work?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

With selenium I try to download something (in order to verify its content), using the following code as a proof-of-concept:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
#Set Location to store files after downloading.
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/tmp")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)

#Set Preference to not show file download confirmation dialogue using MIME types Of different file extension types.
#profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
#                      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False )
profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True )
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","application/zip")
profile.set_preference("plugin.disable_full_page_plugin_for_types", "application/zip")

browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.get('https://www.thinkbroadband.com/download')
time.sleep(15)
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"]')
elem.click()
time.sleep(15)
```

However, nothing 'happens' (i.e. the download is not performed), and also no error message is shown. When I click on that download link manually, the test-file is being downloaded into `/tmp`.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you try to click the link manually to see if the link is working?

Comment: @DebanjanB: Yes that is working, as mentioned in the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be because the click in this case needs to go through a child element

```
elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"]/img')
elem.click()
```

But otherwise when you click on a link browser checks stuff in background for that link, and the site seems to have a problem, when I open the target link in browser I get an empty response

[image: Empty response]

Comment: It does not work: `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//a[@href="http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip”]/img" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.`

Comment: Your double quote got converted to smart quote that is why.. `"` and `”‌` are not same. And when you use double quotes outside you should use `'` single quotes inside. `"//a[@href='http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip'​]/img"`

Comment: Yes I see that now. I work with a Mac... seem to screw it up all the time (because its a Mac...). But it seems to work now!